# how to switch control to silverlight popup

Tags: java, silverlight, selenium, popup

I am using java(selenium) for my application to automate it. When i click on a button a Silverlight popup opens.I dont know how to switch control to this popup and then close it later.

For switching between windows i am using the following code:

```
   for (String handle1 : idriver.getWindowHandles()) {
               idriver.switchTo().window(handle1);
            }
```

but it does not work for Silverlight popup.Please do let me know if my question is missing some information. Many many thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

With WebDriver, you cannot handle Silverlight Controls. Alternatively you can use Sikuli to handle.